# Trying to create an input that only allow user enter word once in this jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Click http://jsfiddle.net/4y1b1j8g/30/ to see. I am trying to create an input that only allow user enter word once. If word 'dog' exist, then user cannot enter dog again. But my code is not working as I expect. help, appreciate.

```js
$("#input").keydown(function(event) {
    var $input = $('#input');
    var txtToMatch = $('#test').text();
    var iLimit = 1;
    var sMatch = $('#input').text().match(txtToMatch);

    if (sMatch !== null && sMatch.length > iLimit) {
        alert('same word')
    }
    else {
            //put input value into div
            var value = $('#input').val();
            $('#test').text($('#test').html() + " " + value);
    }
});
```

```css
.test {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test" id="test">dog</div>
<input type="text" id="input" />
<input type="button" id="button" value="submit" />
```

Comment: You  want to check on submit or on keypress?

Comment: I edit the code again. Sorry for confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had some good ideas in there, but the implementation wasn't quite right.  A couple of key issues:

1. You were using the `keypress` event on the input, so it was firing EVERY time you typed a letter.  In reality, you really want to check on the button click, once the user is done entering their text.
2. You were using `.text` instead of `.val()` to get your input value
3. You were using `.match()` to compare the input to the existing value, when `indexOf()` is a much better match of what you wer tring to figure out (i.e., "Does this word exist in the string yet?").

After addressing those core issues, and making a few other tweaks here and there, the following code appears to do what you were trying to accomplish:

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
    var value = $.trim($('#input').val());

    if (value !== "") {
        var txtToMatch = $('#test').text();
        var iMatch = txtToMatch.indexOf(value);

        if (iMatch !== -1) {
            alert('Word already exists!');
        }
        else {
            //put input value into div
            $('#test').text(txtToMatch + " " + value);
        }
    }
});
```

```css
.test {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test" id="test">dog</div>
<input type="text" id="input" />
<input type="button" id="button" value="submit" />
```

**Edit:** *Yong Wang* also brings up a very good point that, an array is probably a better way to handle your word collection, but, not knowing the full scope of what you are trying to do, I left it as a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way

```
 $("#button").click(function(){
             var value=$('#input').val();
             var toCheck = $('#test').html().split(" ");
             var check = value.split(" ");
             for(var i=0; i<check.length; i++)
             {
             if(toCheck.indexOf(check[i])!==-1) check[i]="";
             }
             $('#test').text($('#test').html() + " " + check.join(" "));     

        });
```

**Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/4y1b1j8g/34/)**

Answer (score 1):

Use an array to keep track of all words

```
var words = [];
words.push($("#test").text());
```

Then check against this array every time the submit button is clicked. If input word not exists in the array, push it to the array

```
    $("#button").click(function(){
        //put input value into div

        var inputText = $.trim($("#input").val());
        if(words.indexOf(inputText)>=0){
            alert("Word exists");
            return;
        }

          words.push(inputText);
        $('#test').text($('#test').html() + " " + inputText);     

    });
```

[FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/ever0702/4y1b1j8g/39/)

Comment: Yeah, an array would definitely be a better way to handle a large collection of words.